# OpenVPN Wrong Subnet

Tags: openvpn

So i Have created an OpenVPN server that is working on my office. The office ip range is 192.168.100.0/24. The vpn is giving the 192.168.1.0/24 range. That is a huge problem for me because when i connect from a remote site that has the same range 192.168.1.0 there are collisions. I tried to change in the server.conf the line

server 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
to
server 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
but it cannot work apparently.

So the main question is how can i make my vpn assign the same range of address as the one on my office. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make the VPN server assign IP addresses from the office range to your clients. Like you said, it won't work.
Instead, you should choose a range which is unlikely to conflict with any other IP address ranges you use, such as:

```
server 10.213.118.0 255.255.255.0
```